# get scm configuration back after accidently deletion from xcode 4

Tags: version-control, xcode4

I would like to know that how do i configure my project(already checked-out) back to my previous repository? I've accidentally deleted all repositories from repositories menu from xcode4. By the way my project was previously configured with xcode 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Organizer window and select the Repositories tab. Click the plus button in the lower-left corner of the window. Choose Add Working Copy... from the menu. Navigate to your project's folder, select it, and click Open.

Assuming all is well with the local copy (or the repo in Git's world), Xcode will Do the Right Thing when displaying the repo status of the members of your working copy in the affected project. If it doesn't, try closing and re-opening the project.

Comment: I don't need git configuration. I need svn from my specific server.

Comment: Same answer. You can just let Xcode know about the working copy by the method I mentioned. If that's not what you're talking about, then you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: @ joshua Nozzi When I use your method. My working copy shows git in place of my server in repositories menu in xcode.

Comment: It sounds like, somewhere along the line, you or Xcode init'd a Git repo in your SVN working directory. Don't know how to help you there without you having to do some messy patching/reverting for SVN. Check out a NEW copy from SVN into another workspace folder and compare/contrast Xcode's behavior. Something's definitely messed up in your current working copy.